# Add and Remove Class Based on Whether Div is Open

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this HTML that goes with the following jQuery:

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="has-sub">iPad <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="iPadAir2.php">iPad Air 2 Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="iPadAir.php">iPad Air Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="iPadMini2.php">iPad mini 2 Review</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">iPhone <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="iPhone6.php">iPhone 6 Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="iPhone5s.php">iPhone 5s Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="iPhone5c.php">iPhone 5c Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="iPhone5.php">iPhone 5 Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="iPhone4s.php">iPhone 4s Review</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub">Mac <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="MacBook.php">MacBook Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="MacBookProRetina.php">MacBook Pro w/ Retina display Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="MacBookPro.php">MacBook Pro Review</a></li>
                <li><a href="MacBookAir.php">MacBook Air Review</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".has-sub").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).parent().children(".has-sub").not(this).find(".sub-menu").slideUp(500);
    });
});
```

As you can see the `i` has a class of `fa-angle-down`. When clicked, the `li` opens but I'd like to remove the class of `fa-angle-down` and add a class of `fa-angle-up` to the `i` class. Could someone please show me how I would do this?

Thanks.

EDIT:

CSS for navigation below.

```
nav {
    background : #034893;
    height : 50px;
}

nav ul,
nav li,
nav a { 
    margin : 0; 
    padding : 0;
}

nav > ul > li {
    color : white;
    display : block;
    float : left;
    font-size : 18px;
    line-height : 50px;
    position : relative;
    transition : all .3s linear;
    width : 25%;
    z-index : 999;
}

nav > ul > li:hover {
    background : #88bffc;
    color : #333;
    cursor : pointer;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
    background : #034893;
    left : 0;
    margin : 0 auto;
    position : absolute;
    right : 0;
    text-align : left;
}

nav ul ul a {
    color : white;
    display : block;
    font-size : 14px;
    padding : 6px 12px;
}

nav ul ul a:hover {
    background : #88bffc;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your css?

Comment: @Chris Did I get it right? disregard the preventDefault, originally I was confused without the styling.

Comment: @zer00ne Perhaps it'd be better if you took a look at the site and then you'd get a better understanding? applefanatic.co.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** This works, checked that the classes are toggling in the DOM.
Edit was to just toggle .fa class initially which toggles on/off the down/up for the menu item that is clicked.

```
$(".has-sub").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;
    $this = $(this);
    $this.find(".sub-menu").slideToggle(500);
    $this.siblings(".has-sub").not(this).find(".sub-menu").slideUp(500);
    $this.find(".fa").toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');
    $this.siblings(".has-sub").not(this).find(".fa-angle-up").toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');
});
```

Comment: This kinda works! It removes the "fa-angle-down" and adds the "fa-angle-up" but when you click again (to close the menu) it doesn't change back to the "fa-angle-down" class.

Comment: @Chris    Editing my answer now to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

When using an anchor `<a>` for something other than going to a location, use [preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). The `fa-angle-down` class was assigned to an italic `<i>` element, when I think you wanted the list item `<li>`. It appears to have an accordion effect, correct? The off and on of the required classes are done with [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). When you have the links pointing to real locations, comment out the `e.preventDefault();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".has-sub").click(function(e) {
    // e.preventDefault();

    $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideToggle(500);
    $(this).parent().children(".has-sub").not(this).find(".sub-menu").slideUp(500);
    $('.fa').not(this).removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
    $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');

  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  background: #034893;
  height: 50px;
}
nav ul,
nav li,
nav a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav > ul > li {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  width: 25%;
  z-index: 999;
}
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background: #88bffc;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav > ul > li > ul {
  background: #034893;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
nav ul ul a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
nav ul ul a:hover {
  background: #88bffc;
}
.fa.fa-angle-up:before {
  content: '\f106 ';
}
.fa.fa-angle-down:before {
  content: '\f107 ';
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<nav class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><i class="fa fa-angle-up">iPad</i>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="iPadAir2.php">iPad Air 2 Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iPadAir.php">iPad Air Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iPadMini2.php">iPad mini 2 Review</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><i class="fa fa-angle-up">iPhone</i>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="iPhone6.php">iPhone 6 Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iPhone5s.php">iPhone 5s Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iPhone5c.php">iPhone 5c Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iPhone5.php">iPhone 5 Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="iPhone4s.php">iPhone 4s Review</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><i class="fa fa-angle-up">Map</i>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="MacBook.php">MacBook Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="MacBookProRetina.php">MacBook Pro w/ Retina display Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="MacBookPro.php">MacBook Pro Review</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="MacBookAir.php">MacBook Air Review</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have read before submitting my post. It's correct that the "i" class has "fa-angle-down". Your code doesn't work. When clicking on one of the "li" that has a class of "has-sub" I'd like to replace the "fa-angle-down" with "fa-angle-up". Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @ChrisI added the fa css from that site, you'll need the correct classes from that specific CSS http://applefanatic.co.uk/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: @ze00ne It's not that. I'm watching the element table in Chrome and it's not adding or removing any class.

Comment: @Chris just add `$(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-angle-down fa-angle-up');` and it'll work.  I'd help with the icon, but I have go to work. I think you'll be able to that easily. :)

Comment: Yes! That works now. Thanks for all the help. Up voted and accepted as the answer :)

Comment: Oh. I thought it worked 100%! It adds the classes fine but if you open a menu and then open another menu, the first menu will still have the up arrow although it should be the down arrow as that menu is shut?

Comment: @Chris ok check it now. I used Font-Awesomes CSS from their own site. Another thing I changed was now the icons start on the up position and the last thing I changed you'll see at the bottom of the CSS, but I don't think it's needed.

Comment: @Chris I also added this for the icons of the columns retracting from another column's extending. `$('.fa').not(this).removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
$(".has-sub").click(function() {
$(this).find('i.fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
    $(this).find(".sub-menu").slideToggle(500);
 $(this).parent().children(".has-sub").not(this).find(".sub-menu").slideUp(500).parents('li').find('i.fa-angle-up').removeClass('fa-angle-up').addClass('fa-angle-down'); 
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add and remove classes. Sometihng like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/j95en0Lp/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="fa-angle">Test (Click me to add a new class)</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-angle{
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-angle-up{
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.fa-angle', function(){
        $(this).addClass('fa-angle-up');
        $(this).removeClass('fa-angle');                     
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.fa-angle-up', function(){
        $(this).addClass('fa-angle');
        $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-up');                     
    });
});
```

*Here I'm just adding and removing classes to change the font color, but you can change the classes to add or remove icons, font color, etc. Hope this help out.*